# error with php file_put_contents--corrupt file

Tags: php, image

I have code that stores images on a server. It stores what appears to be the correct image size on the server. However, when I go to download the file, the file appears is corrupt.

My code is as follows:

```
$img_file2=file_get_contents($img_file);
$file_loc = file_put_contents('/home/photorankr/WWW/userphotos/bigphotos/test16.jpeg',$img_file2);
```

Any ideas on what is wrong? Above, `$img_file` is a url.

Comment: What is the value of `$img_file`?

Comment: @Dave Chen, when I echo $img_file out, it echoes out the url text.

Comment: Make sure that you can view this image without any cookies or any special user-agents.

Comment: @Dave Chen, yes, I can view the image online without any cookies or any special user-agents.

Comment: What's the image in question? Also make sure it's a `.jpeg` and not `.png`.

Comment: Does the new file have the exact same size as the original?

Comment: I think that you might run into issues if you didn't enable the https wrapper and the image was on https://

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: corrupt, how? 0-byte file? extra garbage before/after the expected data? Did you check if either function is returning a boolean false, indicating failure?

Comment: What is the value of $img_file2 after the `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: @Dave Chen I think your right about this. I was trying to pull https content. The file is not 0 byte.

Comment: You can either remove the `s` in `https` or enable it in `php.ini` `extension=php_openssl.dll`.

Comment: Also `allow_url_include = On`. So `file_get_contents` can download remote files.